# Where is MockNgZone for Angular 4

Tags: angular

Angular 2 provided a mock implementation of NgZone called [MockNgZone](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.1/modules/%40angular/core/testing/ng_zone_mock.ts). This doesn't appear to be available in Angular 4. Does anyone know where or why it has gone?

Comment: It's still there, in `@angular/core/testing`: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.x/packages/core/testing/src/ng_zone_mock.ts

Comment: @jonrsharpe Great. But then why can't I seem to import it using `import {MockNgZone} from "@angular/core/testing"`?

Comment: Because it is not private api anymore. `core/testing: Remove the following APIs from @angular/core/testing, which have been deprecated or were never intended to be publicly exported:` https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-13

Comment: A question likelier to solve your problem might be: given the following *usage* of NgMockZone, how can I do this in Angular 4.x?

Answer (score 2):

**Overview:** Angular 4/5/6 still define `MockNgZone` within [@angular/core/testing/src/ng_zone_mock](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/testing/src/ng_zone_mock.ts#L16), however it is not exported publicly. Created December 2017, [Issue #21075: Expose MockNgZone](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21075) is still open on Angular's GitHub account. [Pull Request #21628](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/21628) was started January 2018 and exposes MockNgZone but the PR has never been completed, stalled with a merge conflict since March 2018.

**Option 1:** Re-create `MockNgZone` as a testing utility for yourself.

```js
import { EventEmitter, Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MockNgZone extends NgZone {
  onStable: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(false);
  constructor() { super({enableLongStackTrace: false}); }
  run(fn: Function): any { return fn(); }
  runOutsideAngular(fn: Function): any { return fn(); }
  simulateZoneExit(): void { this.onStable.emit(null); }
}
```

**Option 2:** Angular does publicly export a similar `NoopNgZone` from the [same location](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/zone/ng_zone.ts#L319) as `NgZone` however the implementation is different from `MockNgZone`.

```js
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { NoopNgZone } from '@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [{ provide: NgZone, useClass: NoopNgZone }]
})
```

Comment: `NoopNgZone` is not exported as well. It's suggested to use the `ComponentFixtureNoNgZone` instead. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23594